# About Python append pop reverse order

Tags: python

I want to reverse order to double　reverse:

but this not good idea, i want use while, how can i do to?

Comment: `x[::-1]` is already a reversed version of `x`. If you really want to double reverse it, that's the same as doing nothing, so you don't need a function.

Comment: You want to *what*? Maybe show the desired  output of the operation.

Comment: So,i want to only use append and pop output reverse order to double　reverse

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> listA = [[13, 22, 33,],[4,5, 6],[7,8, 9]]
>>> [list(reversed(inner_list)) for inner_list in reversed(listA)]
[[9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4], [33, 22, 13]]
```

Comment: Thanks, so, i want to only use append and pop, how can i do to?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to reverse both the outer and the inner lists:

```
def reverse_list(x):
    return list(y[::-1] for y in x[::-1])
```

This is is the sample output:

```
>>> reverse_list([[1,'a','b'],[2,'foo',4],[3,'baz']])
[['baz', 3], [4, 'foo', 2], ['b', 'a', 1]]
```

If you **REALLY** want to do it manually (you shouldn't by the way, because it's not very Pythonic), you could do it along the lines of:

```
def reverse_list(x):
    old = x[:] # Copy list
    outer = []
    while old: # While old is not empty
        elem = old.pop()
        inner = []
        while elem: # While elem is not empty
            inner.append(elem.pop())
        outer.append(inner)

    return outer
```

Comment: Thanks, so, i want to use append and pop, how can i do to?

Comment: for example:def reverse_list(x):
    i =len(x)
    j = []
    while i > 0:
        j = j.append(i.pop)
    return j     but this is not work,

Comment: @user3566877 You are trying to do it in a very unnatural way. Why?

Comment: @Tibori know your code, but  i don't know how use while roop and append an d pop